# v.to.3d can't seem to find polygons

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am trying to use the `v.to.3d` algorithm from GRASS in QGIS, but whenever I try to run it, it seems to not be able to find the polygons that I am inputting. This is the result of the operation:

```
Übersteuere die Überprüfung der Projektion. 
Check if OGR layer contains polygons... 
0..20..40..60..80..100 
Importing 5 features (OGR layer )... 
0..20..40..60..80..100 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Registriere Primitive... 

5 primitives registered 
58 Vertices registriert 
Anzahl der Knoten: 5 
Anzahl der Primitive: 5 
Anzahl der Punkte: 0 
Anzahl der Linien: 0 
Anzahl der Grenzen: 5 
Anzahl der Zentroide: 0 
Anzahl der Flächen: - 
Anzahl der Inseln: - 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Säubere Polygone... 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Teile Polygone... 
Breaking polygons (pass 1: select break points)... 
20..40..60..80..100 
Breaking polygons (pass 2: break at selected points)... 
20..40..60..80..100 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Entferne Duplikate ... 
20..40..60..80..100 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Breche Grenzen auf... 
0..20..40..60..80..100 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Entferne Duplikate ... 
20..40..60..80..100 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Säubere Grenzen an den Knoten... 
20..40..60..80..100 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Vereinige Grenzen... 
20..40..60..80..100 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Entferne Überstände (dangles)... 
20..40..60..80..100 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Erzeuge Flächen... 
0..20..40..60..80..100 
5 areas built 
5 isles built 
Anzahl der Knoten: 5 
Anzahl der Primitive: 5 
Anzahl der Punkte: 0 
Anzahl der Linien: 0 
Anzahl der Grenzen: 5 
Anzahl der Zentroide: 0 
Anzahl der Flächen: 5 
Anzahl der Inseln: 5 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Entferne Brücken... 
20..40..60..80..100 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Registriere Primitive... 

5 primitives registered 
58 Vertices registriert 
Erzeuge Flächen... 
0..20..40..60..80..100 
5 areas built 
5 isles built 
Füge Inseln hinzu... 
20..40..60..80..100 
Anzahl der Knoten: 5 
Anzahl der Primitive: 5 
Anzahl der Punkte: 0 
Anzahl der Linien: 0 
Anzahl der Grenzen: 5 
Anzahl der Zentroide: 0 
Anzahl der Flächen: 5 
Anzahl der Inseln: 5 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Finding centroids for OGR layer ... 
0..20..40..60..80..100 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Schreibe Zentroide... 
20..40..60..80..100 
----------------------------------------------------- 
5 Eingabepolygone 
Gesamtfläche: 287732 (5 Flächen) 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Kopiere Objekte... 
10..20..30..40..50..60..70..80..90..100 
Erstelle Topologie für die Vektorkarte ... 
Registriere Primitive... 

10 primitives registered 
63 Vertices registriert 
Erzeuge Flächen... 
0..10..20..30..40..50..60..70..80..90..100 
5 areas built 
5 isles built 
Füge Inseln hinzu... 
20..40..60..80..100 
Füge Zentroide hinzu... 
10..20..30..40..50..60..70..80..90..100 
Anzahl der Knoten: 5 
Anzahl der Primitive: 10 
Anzahl der Punkte: 0 
Anzahl der Linien: 0 
Anzahl der Grenzen: 5 
Anzahl der Zentroide: 5 
Anzahl der Flächen: 5 
Anzahl der Inseln: 5 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>g.region n=148105.584664 s=147145.123923 e=359750.032321 w=358642.909045 res=100 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>v.to.3d input=tmp15299191780717 column="z" output=output0664654415c14e769ffad9b4c1f04820 --overwrite 
Fetching height from column... 
Transformiere Objekte... 

Kopiere Attribute... 
Erstelle Topologie für die Vektorkarte ... 
Registriere Primitive... 

5 primitives registered 
5 Vertices registriert 
Erzeuge Flächen... 
0..20..40..60..80..100 
0 areas built 
0 isles built 
Füge Inseln hinzu... 
Füge Zentroide hinzu... 
20..40..60..80..100 
Anzahl der Knoten: 0 
Anzahl der Primitive: 5 
Anzahl der Punkte: 0 
Anzahl der Linien: 0 
Anzahl der Grenzen: 0 
Anzahl der Zentroide: 5 
Anzahl der Flächen: 0 
Anzahl der Inseln: 0 
WARNUNG: Number of centroids exceeds number of areas: 5 > 0 
WARNUNG: Anzahl der Zentroide außerhalb von Flächen: 5 
Vertikale Ausdehnung der Vektorkarte : B: -10.000000 T: 10.000000 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>v.out.ogr -s -e input=output0664654415c14e769ffad9b4c1f04820 type=auto output="C:\Users\boates\AppData\Local\Temp\processingc9930907ac014481b1dbc560ecab64a2\c2d5d164c00a49a982ba70a6a2de8bce" format=ESRI_Shapefile output_layer=output --overwrite 
Warning 6: '' is an unexpected value for SHPT layer creation option of type string-select. 
ERROR 6: Unknown SHPT value of `' passed to Shapefile layer 
creation. Creation aborted. 

WARNUNG: Unable to determine input map's vector feature type(s). 
WARNUNG: 5 centroids found, but not requested to be exported. Verify 'type' parameter. 
WARNUNG: Vector map is 3D. Use format specific layer creation options SHPT (parameter 'lco') or '-z' flag to export in 3D rather than 2D (default) 
FEHLER: Kann OGR-Layer nicht erzeugen. 

C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin>exit 
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers

The following layers were not correctly generated.
3D
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm
```

I think this is where it first runs into problems:

```
WARNUNG: Number of centroids exceeds number of areas: 5 > 0
```

Why could this be? They are just simple shapefile polygons in a projected EPSG. I was able to do this with polygons earlier with no issue, but using polygons fails every time. I even changed the minimum area to an extremely low number, and snapping is set to `-1` (off), so I don't have any idea why GRASS can't recognize this polygons.

Comment: What kind of data do you try to extrude to 3D? Please edit the original question to add some more intro, thanks.

Comment: I am not extruding, I am converting 2d polygons to 3d. All gave as input was 5 plain polygons, digitzed in qgis and with no attribute beyond an integer id field and a double field with the z value to set as its height. Nothing special about it.

Comment: ... the more we know, the easier to help. Adjacent or overlapping polygons? That makes a difference in topology